# AngularJS 1.5 - How to Set Two Way Bindings on Component

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-components

Directives in Angular 1.X are set to have two way binding by default.  Components have isolated scopes by default.  I have a view that looks like:

```
<div class="my-view">
    {{controllerVariable}}
</div>
```

If I have the above set up as a directive, the `controllerVariable` loads correctly in the following situation:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <my-view></my-view>
</div>
```

But if I have it set up as a component using the following:

```
myApp.component('myView', {
    templateUrl: '/path/to/view',
    bindings: '='
});
```

then the variable value isn't displayed.  I have tried adding `$ctrl` to the variable:

```
<div class="my-view">
    {{$ctrl.controllerVariable}}
</div>
```

but this doesn't display the value either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Two way bindings aren't recommended in Components.  Components were designed to be a compact, re-usable element which is completely stand alone, meaning it has no dependency on the surrounding HTML/JavaScript, and causes no changes to the surrounding HTML/JavaScript either.  Components *can* **communicate** with other app elements, but they should not be able to modify or be modified by other elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to explicitly state the variable I wanted to bind:

```
myApp.component('myView', {
    templateUrl: '/path/to/view',
    bindings: {
        controllerVariable: '@'
    }
});
```

Also, since `controllerVariable` is a string, I had to use the `@` sign binding.

Answer (score 10):

You need to pass the value from the directive into the component:

```
<my-view passed-var='ctrl.passedVar'></my-view>
```

and in the component:

```
myApp.component('myView', {
    templateUrl: '/path/to/view',
    bindings: {
        passedVar: '='
    },
    controller: function () {
      var vm = this;
      console.log(vm.passedVar);
    }
});
```

then you will be able to access in the component as in the example

There are a few other ways to do it, such as using a service to handle the information or using require which would give your component access to the controller of the directive. You can find the above method and others here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component.

Comment: I get an `undefined` in console with this

Comment: `passedVar` in my-view should be `passed-var`

Comment: Yes thanks for following up on that, also you will want to bind ctrl.passedVar appropriately based how you defined your controller (you may just need to remove the ctrl. and use passedVar)